# How to get navigation menu toggle to start closed using Jquery

Tags: jquery, navigation, slidetoggle

I've built my own responsive navigation menu using jQuery and it works to a degree, The problem I'm having is, when viewing it in mobile screen, the menu always starts open. The toggle works and and the navigation works fine apart from this issue.

here is a link to the site http://www.visuallycreative.co.uk

If you shrink the browser window to mobile size then refresh the browser, the menu starts open, I need it to start closed, then open on toggle.

#### jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).on('resize', function() {
        if ($(window).width() <= 640) {
            $('.navbar').hide();
        } else {
            $('.navbar').show();
        }
    });
    $('.toggle').on('click', function() {
        $('.navbar').slideToggle('slow');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See below, instead of adding a `.hide()` I've triggered the `resize` event, so it will only hide on Mobile like you've asked ... basically I'm telling the window to pretend it has resized when the document is ready, so any code inside of your `.on("resize")` will be executed :)

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(window).on('resize', function() {
     if ($(window).width() <= 640 ) {
        $('.navbar').hide();
     }   else {
        $('.navbar').show();
     }
  }).trigger("resize");

  $('.toggle').on('click', function() {
     $('.navbar').slideToggle('slow');
  });

});
```

Comment: nope, doesn't work!, menu is still expanded exposing all the menu items on browser refresh.

Comment: I'm sorry, but yes it does work: http://jsfiddle.net/dd9azku9/ ... I also edited your code on your own website to add the `.trigger("resize")` and it worked there, too...  

for that JS Fiddle, you can resize the `result` box to </> 640px and press __"play"__ to see it in in action. :)

Answer (score 0):

Just add `$('.navbar').hide();` as the first line. You are only telling the window to perform those actions on resize and a page initially loading is not a resize. So, the first line should be to hide the navbar.

Comment: Not strictly correct answer; because it would hide the `.navbar` on `> 640px` too, which seems to not be desired :)